# custom alert dialog is not getting dismissed

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've created a custom dialog where I'm inflating a dialog view with the custom layout here the dialog is successfully shown but when I try to dismiss the dialog nothing happens I tried declaring the dialog as final but it doesn't help.

**Please take a look at my code:**

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemdet, null);
                            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                            name=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
                            img=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.itemdetimg);
                            counter=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                            add=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.add);
                            del=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
                            confirm=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
                            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),  "fonts/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf");
                            name.setTypeface(custom_font);
                            final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                            add.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i++)));
                            del.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i--)));
                            name.setText(docname);
                            Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(img);
                            confirm.setOnClickListener(v->{
                                String qty=counter.getText().toString();
                                if (qty.equals("0")){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Specify Quantity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                    db.collection("Order").document(TableListFragment.tableno)
                                            .update(
                                                    "Items", FieldValue.arrayUnion(docname),
                                                    "Quantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion(qty)
                                            ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.i("WhatdFuck:",e.toString());
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });
                            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Order");
                            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter Order Details");
                          final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                            b.show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: do other function like add and delete in your dialog works?

Comment: Yes they work properly and button click is also working without any problem and i'm getting the toast message that item is addded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem.is that you are calling dialogBuilder.create in two separate places and the alertDialog instance is never shown.

Remove lines:

```
...b = dialogBuilder.create();
b.show();
```

And add in the same place:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

Also you have to fix the order of everything so it works correctly.

- instantiate builder
- add params to builder
- create a dialog by calling dialogBuilder.create()
- create click listener after having a dialog instance
- show dialog

Comment: Thanks that was so silly of me which i didn't notice your solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `alertDialog.dismiss();` to above of  `if (qty.equals("0")){` like this:

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
if (qty.equals("0")){...
```

**Update**

The problem occurred because you are showing different dialog(b) and dismissing different dialog(alertDialog):

`b` and `alertDialog` both are different dialog, so replace these two lines:

```
final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                            b.show();
```

with only this:

```
alertDialog.show();
```

at bottom of your code.

Comment: tried doing that too but doesn't work nothing happens

Comment: where are you clicking to dismiss dialog?

Comment: to dismiss alert dialog i'm simply calling dialog.dismiss() on confirm button click

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Dialog instead of AlertDialog.Builder like below. You can also customize that like;

```
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_my_tasks);
     dialog.setCancelable(true);

     TextView tv_msg = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
     TextView tv_reachedLoc = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_reachedLoc);

     tv_msg .setText("");

     tv_reachedLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                   // dismiss dialog
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                   // do your task here

                                }
                            });

  dialog.show();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked for me but the the exact solution for my problem

Comment: @Mr.V glad that this helps you. You can also accept and upvote this answer, so other devs also find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_itemdet);

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.show();
                            name=dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
                            img=dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemdetimg);
                            counter=dialog.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                            add=dialog.findViewById(R.id.add);
                            del=dialog.findViewById(R.id.sub);
                            confirm=dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
                            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),  "fonts/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf");
                            name.setTypeface(custom_font);
 add.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i++)));
                            del.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i--)));
                            name.setText(docname);
                            Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(img);
                            confirm.setOnClickListener(v->{
                              dialog.dismiss();
                                String qty=counter.getText().toString();
                                if (qty.equals("0")){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Specify Quantity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                                    db.collection("Order").document(TableListFragment.tableno)
                                            .update(
                                                    "Items", FieldValue.arrayUnion(docname),
                                                    "Quantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion(qty)
                                            ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.i("WhatdFuck:",e.toString());
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing dialog in UI thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you just need to use

```
 alertDialog.show();
```

instead of these two lines

```
final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                        b.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last two lines of code. As you are creating two instances of dialog and trying to dismiss the one which you didn't show, it creates problem.

```
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemdet, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        name = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
        img = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.itemdetimg);
        counter = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        add = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.add);
        del = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        confirm = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf");
        name.setTypeface(custom_font);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        add.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i++)));
        del.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i--)));
        name.setText(docname);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(img);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String qty = counter.getText().toString();
            if (qty.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Specify Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                db.collection("Order").document(TableListFragment.tableno)
                        .update(
                                "Items", FieldValue.arrayUnion(docname),
                                "Quantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion(qty)
                        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("WhatdFuck:", e.toString());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Order");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter Order Details");


         alertDialog.show();
```